# Tradeoffs when choosing the op-amp package: quad vs dual vs single

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, design, packages

Let's say as an example that I need to use four op-amps in my project. I don't have any super strict requirement of space and price.

Which are the parameters to take into account when choosing the package to use, beside the space occupied on the board and the total price?
What are the tradeoffs, and what are the differences in using two dual packages or even four different single packages instead of using a quad package? 

Thanks in advance for every answer.

Comment: I don't think there is any major performance difference. It can make the layout easier to take 4 single op-amps. look at this: http://www.planetanalog.com/document.asp?doc_id=528114 They say that it can match the op-amps better because they are very close on the wafer. This may slightly be better for your design. Con's are cross talk, increase in dissipation, layout difficulties and input stage unbalanced.

Comment: What Weaverworm says + opamps in the same package share their supply pins. It depends on your design if this is OK. It usually is.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Why the layout would be easier with four singles? Wouldn't that mean more wires to route?

Comment: If you have four singles you can put them where needed, at opposite corners of the board if you want. With a single package all the wiring goes through the same area.

Comment: @FMarazzi: Opamp or op-amp is shorthand for 'operational amplifier'. It's not an acronym so it doesn't need to be in capital letters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With no exceptions that I can think of, using four op-amps requires that all the op-amps be of the same type. In many cases this means that some of the op-amps will not be optimal in some way. The type you would pick for an output circuit might have high slew rate, high power supply voltage capability, high drive current and be tolerant of capacitive loads, however those characteristics might be unimportant for the front end which requires (say) very low noise, offset voltage and low input bias current. So chances are good something in the performance or cost is being compromised compared to using more part types. There are many types of amplifiers that all co-exist in the market for good reasons.

Crosstalk, which others have mentioned, can take place even at DC in The form of slight shifts in offset voltage of one op-amp with the output voltage of the other- possible significant when they are operating at very different levels. Thermal crosstalk also as mentioned is also possible and can cause distortion or intermodulation.

Layout is often easier with singles or duals compared to quads, in my experience. There is little advantage in board space with quads over duals, however quads can be cheaper per op-amp (the ubiquitous LM324 is typically the same price approximately for the dual and quad so you are almost getting two op-amps for free - except board space and power consumption). Higher performance op-amps usually are not like that.

Modern op-amps include many types that have very limited power supply voltage- perhaps as low as 5V (+/- 2.5V) maximum. Parts with similar performance that can handle +/-15V are much more expensive or unavailable. So using a mix of supply voltages may make sense, which requires different packages.

I can't really answer the question about what parameters are important - **every** number and graph and paragraph in the data sheet and any application notes is important in one application or another, as well as other things which may be unstated or hidden on the datasheet. For example, a cheap LM324 is used in an application where one amplifier is used as a comparator, but the requirement changes and higher performance is required, so the designer substitutes a more precise type, unfortunately the substitute is a wonderful op-amp but does unfortunate things with a large differential input voltage causing much gnashing of teeth and loss of hair. The information is hidden in a block diagram on page 27 of the datasheet where series resistors and back-to-back diodes are shown but not in any performance number since they are not specified under such conditions.

Comment: Is the distribution of input offset voltage across several op amps more narrow if the op amps are in the same package? I am thinking of how transistor characteristics are more similar between transistors that are adjacent on the die. I have a scenario where the worst case stack up of offset voltages in a 3 op amp instrumentation amplifier is unacceptable, but if I can assume the offsets will be similar or at least have the same polarity then the accuracy is acceptable.

Answer (score 9):

1. The thermal effects of having multiple op-amps in a single package may become a concern, as the op-amps output voltage changes so does it's thermal dissipation. This thermal wave will propagate across the chip causing imbalances in the op-amps input. Therefore if you are trying to use a high speed op-amp to drive a low impedance load your thermal dissipation could around 30C difference
2. Furthermore many will share bias circuits internally and improper use of op-amps may cause these circuits to fail for all of the op-amps not just one.
3. Crosstalk, in two forms, both electrical and thermal. Thermal from the wave propagating across the chip will look like low frequency feedback across the input. Electrically as supply pins are shared so a large load in a single section will cause a drop across the bond wires.
4. When using a quad chip or even a dual chip you risk limiting yourself. As all op-amps are identical and therefore you must pick one style/feature whether that be aimed at capacitive loads, slew rate, hpv capability etc. You may be better having many single different op-amps rather than one quad for this reason.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Crosstalk can be a problem in some applications.For Audio stuff which I dont do all the time I use seperate opamps for each channel because the crosstalk can be distorted so its not just stereo seperation . In other words the crosstalk spec appears more than adequate compared to the stereo seperation of normal program material but such an amp sounds ghastley, only to be cured by using seperate chips for each channel.

Answer (score 3):

In the ranges of opamps commonly used for audio (without opening a can of worms) such as the 5532 and tl072, the duals are often cheaper due to increased use, and certainly on a per opamps basis.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from some of the other great answers, a possible negative of quad packages is that they are often missing some pins that can be handy that are present on single and many dual packages, like offset trim.

Comment: Op amps have gotten so good, that if you select the right type for the application, it can be considered ideal for practical purposes. I will go as far as saying that using offset trim in 2015 is just bad design for all but special cases.

Comment: @MattYoung -- agree completely, just adding it for thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

Manufactures typically offer much wider choice of op-amps in dual and singles compared to quads. Price may be over double for a quad, indicating small market demand. Maintaining signal integrity is also more difficult with quads.
If your specs are not demanding then quads can be cheap and commonly available (LM324, TL074 and all the newer +5V single supply quads in TSSOP-14).

Answer (score 1):

In some circuits (differential amplifiers and SDR receivers with I and Q channels) you want matched components.  If an op amp is on the same die it will more likely have the same specs, kind of like a sheet of cookies.  They are all burned or just right.  :-)